# Asp Boilerplate,,, How to create New Menu in Menu bar?

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I want to add a new menu in menu bar, i created a class according to Boilerplate documents, but don't know how to configure menu,, And menu is for all users,, Here is code which i have done yet
I created a class extended from navigation provider

```
  public class NavigationsProviderMenu : NavigationProvider
{
    public override void SetNavigation(INavigationProviderContext context)
    {
        context.Manager.MainMenu
        .AddItem(
            new MenuItemDefinition(
                "Jobs",
                new LocalizableString("Jobs", "ShipperBuyerV1"),
                url: "/JobsList",
                icon: "fa fa-tasks"
                ));
    }

}
```

Comment: Not clear, what actually do you want and what problems did you face?

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov I want to add new menu . How to add new menu ion asp Boilerplate ?

Comment: Just add another `.AddItem(...).AddItem`

Comment: Thanks man. Add this to answer pane I will mark it as true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should sequentially call `AddItem` as a chain and all corresponding menu items will be at same level:

```
context.Manager.MainMenu
    .AddItem(
        new MenuItemDefinition(
            "Jobs",
            new LocalizableString("Jobs", "ShipperBuyerV1"),
            url: "/JobsList",
            icon: "fa fa-tasks"
        ))
    .AddItem(
        new MenuItemDefinition(
            "Another",
            new LocalizableString("Another", "ShipperBuyerV1"),
            url: "/Another",
            icon: "fa fa-tasks"
        ));
```